# How to rsync my node.js project to my intel edison board, through ssh?

Tags: uploading

I would love to get rid of Intel's heavy XDK software, and be able to quickly push the updates of my node.js code into my Intel Edison (arduino compatible) board.

I tried this: `rsync -avz ./ root@192.168.100.177:/node_app_slot/`

But `rsync` is not installed on the board.

How would you do this?

Comment: By installing rsync onto the edison?  I am not familiar with the flavour of Linux that Intel chose - what is it?

Comment: It's based on Yocto, which makes it not exactly trivial to add stuff, if one doesn't have previous exposure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few options:

1. use the Yocto sdk to compile rsync and then deploy it
2. switch to [Debian](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/loading-debian-ubilinux-on-the-edison) and then use the standard way to deploy rsync
3. use scp, like the OP wrote, using the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105140/how-to-copy-only-new-files-using-scp-command) from Rick

If you are already looking for a more typical Unix way of doing things, option 2 might be the most efficient for you, in the long run.
I have not tried it, but AFAIK it should be possible to revert easily, since Edison uses dfu for system upgrades, so you should be able to go back to the stock SW, in case you do not like the Debian installation.

Comment: How can you *not* like a Debian installation?!

Comment: Heh, I like it so much that I wrote the full howto for Galileo: https://sourceforge.net/p/galileodebian/wiki/DebianOnGalileo

Probably it sort of works also for Edison, assuming one has a microSD adapter, for supporting a less space limited installation.
But I haven't had time to try it.

Answer (score 1):

rsync works by talking to the rsync executable running on the remote target; without said executable you will need to drop to either scp or a tar pipe.